# Why is tail.previous returning a null

Tags: c#, data-structures, linked-list, stack

Im implementing a stack using a linked list. I am having trouble with my pop method where tail.previous is null. I think this is because im trying to assign to the node after the tail which doesnt exist. if this is the case, how can i fix it.

```
    class DynamicStack<T>
{
    private class Node
    {
        public T element { get; private set; }
        public Node Next { get; set; }
        public Node Previous { get; set; }

        public Node(T element, Node prevNode)
        {
            this.element = element;
            Next = null;
            Previous = null;
            if (prevNode != null) 
                prevNode.Next = this;
        }
    }


    private Node head, tail;



    public int Count { get; private set; } 


    public DynamicStack()
    {
        this.head = null;
        this.tail = null;
        this.Count = 0;
    }



    public T Pop()
    { 
        if (Count == 0)
            return default(T);
        Node temp = tail;
        tail = tail.Previous;
        Count--;
        return temp.element;
    }


}
```

I have tried doing the pop method as below but it doesnt follow LIFO so its not correct.

```
 public T Pop()
    { 
        if (Count == 0)
            return default(T);
        Node temp = head;
        head = head.Next;
        Count--;
        return temp.element;
    }
```

Comment: You haven't shown where you are assigning `head` or `tail`, and also, you seem to never assign `Node.Previous` to a non-null value.  Did you mean for your constructor to be `Previous = prevNode;` instead of `Previous = null;`?

Comment: @KirkWoll assigning 'Previous = prevNode' solved the issue.

Comment: Since when did a stack have a head and a tail?

Comment: The Node subclass should only take one parameter for the element, and set this.previous and this.next to null. A doubly linked list is not needed for a stack or a queue, so Node should only have a next or a previous member, not both.